# 21.04: Failure to resolve .local hostname from within VM (VMware Workstation)

Tags: dns, vmware, 21.04

**TL;DR**:
What do I need to configure so I can resolve a `.local` hostname on my VM guest as if I was resolving it on my VM host.

**Long version**:
I'm running a VM with Ubuntu 21.04 on my Windows 10 using VMware Workstation (16.1.1 build-17801498). Ubuntu itself is almost vanilla, I've changed next to nothing about the OS/env itself (actually nothing comes to mind right now). Maybe it's noteworthy I upgraded from a previous version of Ubuntu, I believe it was 20.04.

On the host, I can resolve `foo.bar.local` just fine using *nslookup*:

```
> nslookup foo.bar.local
Server:  <...>
Address:  10.73.1.9

Name:    <...>
Address:  10.132.0.30
Aliases:  foo.bar.local
```

On the guest, the same attempt to resolve fails by default

```
> host foo.bar.local
Host foo.bar.local not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

but I can resolve the name if I tell *host* to use the same DNS server which responded earlier on the (VM) host:

```
> host ordermanagement-migration.comventure.local 10.73.1.9
Using domain server:
Name: 10.73.1.9
Address: 10.73.1.9#53
Aliases: 

foo.bar.local is an alias for hello.world.local.
hello.world.local has address 10.132.0.30
```

So I was thinking "why not just use that server always?" and tried to configure it via the network manager GUI: open network settings, go to IPv4 tab, disable "automatic" and enter the IP in the field. Since my VM has two interfaces configured (host-only network & normal NAT for public inet access) and just to be safe, I did this for both interfaces. To my surprise no amount of waiting time after confirming those changes actually led to an observable change in the output of `systemd-resolve --status`: For both interfaces, it just kept the respective `a.b.c.1` address as DNS server. Instead, I had to first dis- then enable the interfaces, after which the server IP is showing up:

```
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (ens33)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 10.73.1.9
       DNS Servers: 10.73.1.9

Link 3 (ens38)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 4 (docker0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

I didn't understand why for `ens38` (public inet access), no DNS server was shown anymore at all. At this point things got even more confusing because enabling an interface (in network manager) on which I had previously disabled "automatic" for DNS suddenly showed "automatic" as enabled but also listed the manual DNS IP and `systemd-resolve --status` yet I still could not resolve `foo.bar.local`.

I've also tried to set `10.73.1.9` as the primary DNS server directly in the NAT/DNS settings of VMware workstation but to no avail.

So how can I get `foo.bar.local` to be resolvable on my (VM) guest by default, in other words without having to specify `10.73.1.9` as nameserver to use - which I cannot do in the application context where I need `foo.bar.local` resolvable.

addendum: There is a VPN involved on my VM host in case that might be relevant. I keep it enabled & connected at all times when using the (VM) host.

Comment: Adding a VPN setup will override the DNS servers if the remote VPN server says "Use these DNS servers instead".  That's likely interfering with your DNS resolution.

Comment: You mean the VPN setup instructs VMware to override its own DNS settings ? Is there a way to disable this ?

Comment: It instructs *Ubuntu* to change the DNS settings, this is usually the case when you have a 'corporate' environment and want to use split DNS and such.  Disabing can only be done on the remote VPN side of things where they change settings or such on the server (so not an option for you). The only otherw way to override this is, post activation of the VPN, run a separate script to set the DNS yourself.  Alternatively, alter `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and set `DNS=` to your primary DNS server you want - uncommenting the line of course - then restarting your computer.